# How append id to path in php

Tags: php, path

i am trying to passing id index page to another page as given below

```
 $id=48;

 header("Location: ".$redirect."parties.php&id=$id");
```

but its not working please help me

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Change the `&` to a `?`

```
header("Location: ".$redirect."parties.php?id=$id");
```

Then in `parties.php`, you'll be able to access it with `$_GET['id']`

Answer (score 4):

```
header("Location: ".$redirect."parties.php?id=$id");
```